# JavaScript regex cant get all matches

Tags: javascript, regex

Code is very simple, but i cant figure out where is the problem:

```
var str = '789a54bc2';
var matches = str.match(/\d*/);
```

I expect to see three entries in matches var (789, 54, 2), but there is just first entry (789).

Where is my mistake? Ty!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var str = '789a54bc2';
var matches = str.match(/\d+/g);
```

Use `+`, otherwise you'll get empty results in your matches array.

A great reference may be located [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp#Special_characters_in_regular_expressions) and tells you everything you could possibly want to know about RegEx in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I hate that little regex implementation differences in programming languages.